# How to get value labels of .sav in python (I'm using savReaderWriter)

Tags: python-3.x, spss

Does anyone know how to get the value labels for certain variables. Surely this needs to be done during the reading of the file as once it is in python it doesnt hold any other information?

This is how im reading in files:

```
with SavReader('foo.sav',ioUtf8=True,returnHeader=True) as reader:
    records=reader.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using:

```
import savReaderWriter as sav
with sav.SavHeaderReader('foo.sav', ioUtf8=True) as header:
    metadata = header.all()
    labels = metadata.valueLabels
```

See the SavHeaderReader documentation here for more information:
https://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/generated_api_documentation.html?highlight=returnheader#savheaderreader